# How to install ViewNX-i on macOS Mojave?

Tags: installation, photos

I want to install Nikon's ViewNX-i on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 to convert photos from NEF to JPEG. I followed the installation steps [here](https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/download/sw/29.html) but cannot see the app: nothing is listed as Nikon or ViewNX in the two application folders (`/Applications` and `~/Applications`). Normally the location would be `/Applications/Nikon Software` but I don't have that. The last modified file in those folders is not from today. I tried three times and the installer says

```
The installation is complete. Is it OK to exit the Install Center?
```

None of the steps in installing the app take more than 1-2 seconds, which seems suspicious. Below are the screenshots of the installation steps.

How can I install Nikon's ViewNX-i?

[image: first screenshot in installation]

[image: second screenshot in installation]

[image: third screenshot in installation]

[image: fourth screenshot in installation]

Comment: Did you see this : [ViewNX 2 Nikon software doesn't work with OS X El Capitan](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7260763)

Comment: That file name bothered me, so I went to have a look on Nikon. Current version is 1.4, your file shows as 1.0 - seems Google doesn't care which version it links to & Nikon's site doesn't automatically find the latest. Going directly through Nikon's search I got his link instead - https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/download/sw/141.html

Comment: I tweaked the link on the original QA over on Graphics Design too, so it now hopefully always finds the latest version.

Comment: @lx07 That link was not exactly my problem but I like the ability to install incompatible software on a previous OS and copy the directories to the new OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your downloaded dmg looked like a very old version (which was initially [my fault from another question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/131645/how-to-batch-convert-raw-nef-to-jpeg-in-gimp)) so the better link would be

https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/220/ViewNX-i.html

Which *should* always link to the latest version.